# axios interceptor's error function is called multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

I am using axios interceptors to log all the api errors to a backend server at one common place. The problem is, if one api call fails the logError function is called multiple times and multiple duplicate requests were sent for logging.

Here's my code

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
    return response;
},
error => {
    logError(error.message);
    return Promise.reject(error);
})
```

Comment: Where is your interceptor added? If it's inside a function that is always called (or multiple times called), that should be the problem. Please provide more code regarding this interceptor that you're using.

Comment: Interceptor code is added in app.js file which will be rendered only once. Also, this is happening only when the backend api is throwing error. I see multiple interceptor calls happening at a time.

Answer (score 6):

This might be issue that your interceptor code initialized multiple times, I was facing the same issue and when it initialized once, solved the issue.